# Spring Boot Webflux and suspend functions cannot be evaluated in Intellij Idea (this@HelloController is not captured)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, intellij-idea, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

In intellij idea evaluating (Cmd + F8 or Option + click) suspended functions while debugging works just fine.
The problem arises in combination with webflux and suspended functions.
Once suspended you cannot evaluate the captured variables any longer.
Error states: `this@HelloController is not captured`

One workaround is to create a `coroutineScope` around an endpoint.
Not sure why this is working at all and have not tested any performance impacts on this.
Searching for a proper way to be able to debug suspended endpoints in intellij with webflux and coroutines, without having to add this `coroutineScope` and an explanation why it's not working otherwise.

```kotlin
@RestController
class HelloController(
    val helloService: HelloService,
) {

    @GetMapping("hello")
    suspend fun hello() =
        helloService.hello() // Throws error when evaluated

    @GetMapping("helloCoroutine")
    suspend fun helloCoroutine() = coroutineScope {
        helloService.hello() // Works just fine when evaluated
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Service
class HelloService {

    suspend fun hello(): String {
        delay(10)
        return "hello there!"
    }
}
```

Complete code can be found here: https://github.com/Ch4s3r/webflux_coroutines_test

Comment: This is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-21425.

Comment: Since Spring Boot 3.0.0 with Java 17, Intellij can now properly debug coroutines with Webflux.